# Android Layout creating problems while switching from portrait to landscape with relative and linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to create UI for login page with logo two edit text and login button, things were very nice in phone portrait mode but when i checked it in landscape and Tablet then the problem started.

i got two solutions

**1.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fed2db"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_parents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutbasic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin20"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="demo@rohitpro.com"
                    android:hint="UserName"
                    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#f7f7f7"
                    android:layout_below="@id/userName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:text="Password@123"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/password"
                    android:background="#f7f7f7"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonForgotPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonLogin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Forgot Password ?"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="@null" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
                android:layout_above="@id/relativelayoutbasic"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this works perfect in portrait mode but as we rotate in landscape it decrease the image size.

show the example below in portrait
[image]

show the example below in Landscape[image]

So i tried the next Solution

**2.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3996db"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_parentscroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_parents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutbasic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin20"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin20"

                >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="demo@rohitpro.com"
                    android:hint="UserName"
                    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#f7f7f7"
                    android:layout_below="@id/userName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:text="Password@123"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/password"
                    android:background="#f7f7f7"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonForgotPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonLogin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Forgot Password ?"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:background="@null" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**A.** In this solution we cannot use the property android:layout_centerInParent="true"
as it is for relative layout so we are not able to make the login text fields center as we did in solution one, this solution looks good in smaller screens and has scroll also but not working on large screens as it will not come in center.

**B.** we are not able to use relative layout inside scrollview as it create so many other complications.

i spend so much time, use so many stack overflow references and others also but nothing is working.

please suggest some way to work on it.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are using `@mipmap/ic_launcher` image with width/height `"wrap_content"`.
So the `ImageView` size will base on `ic_launcher` image size
And the `ic_launcher` image size is smaller in landspace than portrait
=> Your `ImageView` in landscape is smaller than portrait

Therefore, simple set the width for your `ImageView`, then your image size will look same in both portrait and landscape

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageview"
  android:layout_width="100dp" // or whatever you want
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

Comment: if i will add the width, then for different devices it will remain same and will not look good on every device. One more thing i tried putting bigger size images for landscape but it didn't work.

Comment: @RohitChaturvedi you know how to use dimen right?, try using create different dimen for you image width. Moreover, you can also create more layout file for specific screensize

Comment: yes, that's a great suggestion, i totally missed the use of dimen. I am sure that will definitely work. I will further post if it will not solve the problem. Thanks Phan Van Linh

Answer (score 1):

While opening apps in landscape mode, Android first checks if there is any layouts specific to landscape, and if yes, loads it instead of the layouts specified in the *layouts* folder. To do so, you will need to create a new folder ***res/layout-land***, and then copy the layout from the ***layouts*** folder to this folder, and then edit it and make a beautiful landscape layout.

Comment: I totally agree with your point and that way it will work also but i want to work with only one Layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an specified l**ayout-land** or even **layout-sw600dp-land** for tablets.

Comment: yes i can work but but i want to work with only one Layout. –